# How to remove first few lines of CSV in Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

This is the input I am using for logstash.

```
ItemId,AssetId,ItemName,Comment
11111,07,ABCDa,XYZa
11112,07,ABCDb,XYZb
11113,07,ABCDc,XYZc
11114,07,ABCDd,XYZd
11115,07,ABCDe,XYZe
11116,07,ABCDf,XYZf
11117,07,ABCDg,XYZg
Date,Time,Mill Sec,rows,columns
19-05-2020,13:03:46,534,2,2
19-05-2020,13:03:46,539,2,2
19-05-2020,13:03:46,544,2,2
19-05-2020,13:03:46,549,2,2
19-05-2020,13:03:46,554,2,2
```

I need to remove first 8 lines from the csv and make the next line as column header and parse rest of lines as usual. Is there a way to do that in logstash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using the file input and then read it line by line using grok to make sure it has the right amount of fields comma separated and ignore the header one

Your input will look like this:

```
input { 
  file {
    path => "/path/to/my.csv"
    start_position => beginning
  }
}
```

This will read each line into an event with the data in the field named message and then send it to your filters.
In your filter you'll use grok with a pattern like this:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => [
      "^%{DATE:Date},%{TIME:Time},%{NUMBER:Mill_Sec},%{NUMBER:rows},%{NUMBER:colums}$"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This will present each line as an event looking like this:

```
{
  "colums": "2",
  "Time": "13:03:46",
  "Mill_Sec": "554",
  "rows": "2",
  "Date": "19-05-2020"
}
```

You can use mutate to remove unwanted fields (like message) prior to going to your output part. If there is no match with the pattern defined you'll get a tag with the value `_grokparsefailure` in your tags, you can use that to decide to send it to your output or not. As you defined that it has to be numbers, it will also fail on the header one and thus leave you with only 'real' events.

This can be done by having your output defined like this:

```
output {
  if "_grokparsefailure" not in [tags] {
    elasticsearch {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do I have to mention each and every field in the `grok` `match` filter for the header or only the first one like _Date_ will work for the entire row?

Comment: Nice thinking! If the number of fields is a reliable indicator, one could even use a regex conditional like `if !([message] =~ /^([^,]*,){6}[^,]*$/) { drop {} }`. After that, a regular `csv` filter would work fine

Comment: The repeat count on that regex pattern should actually be `4` of course

Comment: grok is creating new fields in your event and thus the naming of the created field is happening by the pattern, that's why you need to mention each one, you can mutate it afterwards (for example combine the date and time fields and then send them to `@timestamp` and get rid of everything else in order to make the event as small as possible

Answer (score 1):

You should do this before the file gets to Logstash. There *are* ways to do it within Logstash, for example by using a `mutliline` code then doing exotic `grok` matches to remove the first N lines (or removing lines until a particular regex), then doing a `split` followed by a plain ol' `csv` filter. You need to be even more careful than usual with header rows. It's a big mess.

Much better to put something in front of Logstash to handle this issue.

If the files are local to your logstash instance, you could use the [Exec input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-exec.html) to deal with the irregularities.

```rb
input {
  exec {
    command => "/path/to/command_or_script" # sh or py or js etc
    interval => 60
  }
}
```

On Linux, this `command` will print a file from the 8th line on...

```
     command => "tail +8 /path/to/file"
```

This one (again for Linux) will drop everything until a line that starts with `date`, and print everything after that

```
    command => "sed -n -e '/^date/,$p' /path/to/file"
```

You can avoid read the same file over and over again by deleting or archiving it in a script (rather than a one-liner as used in these examples)

After trimming the unwanted leading lines, you should be able to use the `csv` filter in a normal way.

Note that if you want to `autodetect_column_names` that pipeline workers must be set to 1.

Comment: Can you provide the code for process mentioned in the first para of doing in logstash?

Answer (score 0):

Your content is not CSV format. Your task is convert it to true CSV format.

Comment: I have changed it to csv. Please reply if you know the solution.

Comment: I mean CSV has only a header row at top row. Your content has 2 title rows. I checked parameter list, no one for your purpose: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-csv.html#plugins-filters-csv-source

Comment: Ignore the first header row, can you skip the rest 7 rows and make the line after that as column header in logstash?